# Enable users edit permission only for items added by him in a list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx, spfx-extensions, office-365-developer

I have the below requirement in SharePoint Online and On-prem versions:

A custom list is to be maintained where users can edit only items that were created by him/her. Enabling unique permission for each item is not an option as the list is expected to have large number of item. Also, the user should be able to add new items. If a user tries to edit items created by other user, he/she should get an error message informing that this action is not allowed.

Could you please suggest if this is possible by using any dev options in SharePoint and/or Power Platform?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an option under the advanced properties of a list that I think does exactly what you want. Just click the 3 dots next to a list in your site contents, click Settings and click Advanced Settings.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved with help of item level permission on list or library.

- Use below step to enable through SharePoint UI.

1. Go to list settings-> Advanced settings-> enable below settings from screen shot.

[image: Item Level Permission]

- Use below PnP PowerShell to enable this settings.

```
 # connect to sharepoint online site
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url "https://Your-SharePoint-Site" -Interactive

 # List name
 $ListName= "Travel requests" 

 # get the list
 $List = Get-PnPList $ListName -Includes ReadSecurity

 # set list item-security
 $List.ReadSecurity = 2 # read items that were created by the user
 $List.WriteSecurity = 2 # create items and edit items that were created by the user
 $List.Update()
 Invoke-PnPQuery
```

Where:

- Create and edit All items: 1
- Create items and edit items that were created by the user: 2
- None: 4

> *Please note, These settings will not have any effect for Site owners and administrators!*

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this certainly works for lists. Is there anyway to implement the same in SharePoint Online Document library?

Comment: For document library you can not enable it through UI. Use PnP PowerShell from above answer. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the response. If we use PS script to enable this feature, it hides all documents created by other users. Is it possible to to keep read only permission on docs uploaded by other users?

Comment: above script will enable the item level permission.  in case if you want apply unique permission - refer this Microsoft docs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/customize-permissions-for-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-02d770f3-59eb-4910-a608-5f84cc297782